# Ruby on Rails RubyMine setup for win 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, installation, rubymine

I am trying to find a tutorial or a document or what ever which will show all the real steps with details how to setup my win 7 pc in order to debug - deploy a rails app through rubymine. I have found only spare pieces of the puzzle which i don't know how to connect.
I am newbie to ruby stuff, that's why i need details steps.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the rails installer.

http://railsinstaller.org

And then rubymine, and you should be good to.

That said, windows is less than ideal to do ruby develoment on. I did it for a while, and I spent to much time fighting the fact that ruby is best on a Unix based system. You can install  ubuntu on a virtual machine and used than for your rails needs.

I think the best day to do this is to use vagrant. Check this http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2368-rmw2013-ready-to-code-automate-your-development-environment

Comment: Thks a lot for your response. I have done it on ubuntu with out rubymine, simple text editor and everythng ok. I just wondering if i could do it  on win. I will continue on ubuntu. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Have you seen [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)? It is a really good editor for rails. Please accept my answer if you find it good enough.

Comment: Thanks but i am microsoft oriented and i have used to not put effort to debug and to deploy. Sublime as i have seen, is not development studio as RubyMine.

Comment: why don't you use RubyMine on [ubuntu?](http://mattslay.com/installing-rubymine-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: As i on my first comment, i will do it becuase as i can see is the only way. :)

Comment: I remember years ago I could install Ruby (not rails) on my Windows PC and start making GUI apps right away. Why is it so much more difficult for Rails?